# find highest value of a particular property in multiple files

Tags: bash, search, grep, pattern-matching

I have multiple files with pattern of "*.tps (example:tps-20170307170421560-1053.tps)" in my log directory(files are in different sub directories).

entries in files are given below. I want to extract highest value of endtime accross all files.

> "endTime :1488902691462"

Entries in file

```
{"endTime":1488902691462,"startTime":1488902691462,"operationIdentity":"publishCacheStatistics","name":"murex.limits.utilities.cache.statistics.CacheStatisticsTimerTask","context":{"parentContext":{"id":-1,"parentContext":null},"data":[{"value":"GlobalRuleCache:Util_Algos_Ctp_Notional_Bar:ValidationRuleRepository","key":"name"},{"value":"0","key":"hits"},{"value":"0","key":"misses"},{"value":"0","key":"count"},{"value":"0","key":"maxElements"},{"value":"0","key":"evictions"},{"value":"Default","key":"policy"}],"id":0}}
{"endTime":1488902691471,"startTime":1488902691471,"operationIdentity":"publishCacheStatistics","name":"murex.limits.utilities.cache.statistics.CacheStatisticsTimerTask","context":{"parentContext":{"id":-1,"parentContext":null},"data":[{"value":"GlobalRuleCache:Diff_Bar_No_Engine:ValidationRuleRepository","key":"name"},{"value":"0","key":"hits"},{"value":"0","key":"misses"},{"value":"0","key":"count"},{"value":"0","key":"maxElements"},{"value":"0","key":"evictions"},{"value":"Default","key":"policy"}],"id":9}}
```

Comment: ...1462 is not even the largest value in the sample data. By "highest" do you mean "smallest"?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you. I have tried this with GNU awk.

```
awk -v RS=':|,' '/endTime/{getline;val=val>$0?val:$0} END{print val}' Input_file
```

**Explanation:** Making record separator as : OR , then trick is searching for string endTime in a line, if it founds it then using getline(which will jump to next line), now here checking if val's value is greater than it's previous value if it is NOT then keep it as it is else replace it with new value of it. At last printing the value of val.

Comment: downvoter, could you please let me know the reason for -ve? Would like to request you to let me know.

Comment: I tested your reply and it worked on Ubuntu perfectly. Clever way. I upvoted, dont know why would someone  downvote.

Comment: @MatiasBarrios, thanks mate for encouragement, keep learning and keep sharing.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : thanks for reply. its not working on solaris box :(

bash$ awk -v RS=':|,' '/endTime/{getline;val=val>$0?val:$0} END{print val}'
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 :  even i didn't voted down. some guy voted down to my question as well. at least they should mention reason for it.

Comment: @AnkitGoyal, on a Solaris/SunOS system, change awk to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk , /usr/xpg6/bin/awk , or nawk and let me know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: I found awk in xpg4 dir. command is running since 5 mins and no output is showing yet. even though there is only 2 files in my log directory.

Comment: Did you provide any Input_file name while running it? Or how did you run the command?

Comment: can we provider directory location ? I have multiple files in different sub directories. Even if i provide single file its showing   output as "1488906327152,"startTime""

Comment: Did you try with nawk? Because I think that is most newest one. Also I haven't tested this in Sun os as I don't have it. Let me know on same.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data looks like JSON, use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to parse them:

```
shopt -s globstar
jq -r .endTime **.tps | sort -n | head -1
```

That gets the **smallest** value. If you want the **largest** use `tail -1`

Comment: true, but the simple text files contain JSON-formatted data.

Comment: okay thanks but was looking some thing in bash script. I forget to mention earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me.

```
find . -name '*.tps' -exec sed '/endTime/!d; s/{//; s/,.*//' {} + | sort -r | head -1
```